# Most reliable way to identify a stock rocketing up

Tags: stocks, trading

I'm trying to determine the most reliable way to identify a stock about the rise in value drastically.

Is there a method or data points to query based on volume/simple moving average for example or some other criteria that can provide this information from say the past 24-72 hours?

Example: on Jan. 4th, 2016 EnteroMedics Inc. (ETRM) when from 2.09 to 27.70 in under 7 days.

Comment: If there were a way to do this, it would be pre-programmed into any/all automated trading software and used by professional brokerage firms until the opportunity no longer existed. Wanting to do this is a pipedream, equivalent to asking how to know what number the roulette wheel will hit. Money just doesn't come that easily.

Comment: LOL - did you not notice there was a reverse split, you got one share for every 70 you held? This stock did not go up tenfold but it dropped like the proverbial rock.

Comment: Invent a time machine

Comment: Updated the question to clarify that I'm referring to reviewing recent trading action.

Answer (score 10):

> Is there a method or data points to query based on volume/simple
>   moving average for example or some other criteria that can provide
>   this information?

No, of course not.

That would involve predicting the future. And magic eight balls are just toys, Ouija boards are just for play, and tarot cards are just cardboard.

The past 24-72 hours is not a predictor of the future 24-72 hours or anything else. Stocks go up, stocks go down, and they don't follow a short-term pattern that you can read ahead of time. Afterwards, yes - but in the middle, no.

You can look at pretty graphs like uptrends, and try to invest into a trough. The problem is there's no way to predict how many peaks and troughs an uptrend will have before a reversal. It may be one, it may be many. The same holds true for any other pattern-based investment attempt.

Basically you have to guess the correct time to get out as well as the correct time to get in. You might get lucky twice, or you might not.

The only way to identify a stock rocketing up is:

- define what you mean by "rocketing up"
- look for that happening in the recent past
- gamble that it will continue to happen
- place your bet
- keep ypur fingers crossed
- decide when to get out
- if you are successful once, admit that it was luck, not skill

Good luck.

Comment: I re-phrased the question.  I meant by analyzing the data from the last couple of days.

Comment: No can do, Rocco. Short term trends store effectively unpredictable from the numbers; you need a deep understanding of the company and how it is likely to react to news... then hope you see the right news. Of get out of short-term gambling and into long-term buy-and-hold investment.

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco, that is the worst advice ever by keshlam. Ask him how he went during the GFC in 2008. Buy & hold is the worst advice and is more relying on hope than anything else. So in essence buy & hold could be considered gambling, since what you do in gambling is hoping you win.

Comment: Long-term buy-and-hold of a widely diversified set of index funds across asset classes isn't what I'd call gambling. That's how I weathered the "GFC in 2008". Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, so what were your returns in 2008, I made almost 15%, and a friend of mine made over 100%. Buy & hold is gambling and diversification is for losers, a way to reduce your potential profits.

Comment: @MarkDoony - "Buy & hold is gambling and diversification is for losers" - got it. Good luck with that.

Comment: For what it's worth, I too came out of the Great Recession with no damage. Quicken claims my average annual return over 20 years is 10% despite several such market corrections/dips over the years, and I think it is undercounting some things. That is good enough for me given that I am putting near zero effort into it and not taking much risk, it's good enough that I could retire now if I wanted to.

Comment: Btw, I did do a bit of contrarian buying during the Great Recession... But that was speculation, based n the unsupported hope that the markets would only take a few years to recover, and it was still based on long-term value rather than short-term pattern trading. I don't have figured available on exactly how that speculation played out independent of the rest of my investments; I know I made money on it overall and probably doubled what I was lucky enough to put in near the bottom, but my focus was on taking advantage of fire-sale pricing on things I'd buy and hold anyway.